# Replace list of data from one file YAML to another file preserving the format(indentation)

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, jq, yq

I have a below `YAML` file called file1.yaml

```
default:
  app:
    service-v1:
      country:
        list: LIST_TO_REPLACE
```

I am trying to replace **LIST_TO_REPLACE** text with the below `YAML` file list data.

**file2.yml**

```
app:
  list-data: // Need to extract this node data and replace in the file1.yml
    - key1: value
      key2: value
      key3: 
        - list1
        - list2
        - list3
    - key4: value
      key5: value
      key6: 
        - list1
        - list2
        - list3
```

I am using `YQ` to replace the list of data from **file2** to **file1**. But it is not correctly indented in **file1**.

Is there any way to replace the entire node and it could follow the indentation of **file1**?

**Expected Output:**

```
default:
  app:
    service-v1:
      country:
        list: //After replace operation
          - key1: value
            key2: value
            key3: 
          - list1
          - list2
          - list3
          - key4: value
            key5: value
            key6: 
          - list1
          - list2
          - list3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have tagged `jq`, I assume you are looking for a solution using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). Here's one using `input` for the second file:

```bash
yq -y '
  .default.app."service-v1".country.list = input.app."list-data"
' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

```json
default:
  app:
    service-v1:
      country:
        list:
          - key1: value
            key2: value
            key3:
              - list1
              - list2
              - list3
          - key4: value
            key5: value
            key6:
              - list1
              - list2
              - list3
```

---

For a solution using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could use `load` to read the second file.

```bash
yq '
  .default.app."service-v1".country.list = load("file2.yaml").app."list-data"
' file1.yaml
```

```json
default:
  app:
    service-v1:
      country:
        list:
          - key1: value
            key2: value
            key3:
              - list1
              - list2
              - list3
          - key4: value
            key5: value
            key6:
              - list1
              - list2
              - list3
```

Note: With this implementation of yq, you can also use the `-i` flag to modify `file1.yaml` in-place.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working like a charm. Can we search the TEXT to replace using the select() method in `yq`, instead of going node by node(key1.key.2.key3)?

Comment: Huh, interesting, I wasn't aware that there were two different yq implementations

Comment: @AvinashMishra Sure, replace the LHS with `(.. | select(. == "LIST_TO_REPLACE"))` (works with both versions).

Comment: @knittl Yes, unfortunately them having the same name leads to lots of confusion. See also SO's [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info)

Comment: You can also use gojq, the Go implementation of jq, with the same program, but with the invocation: `gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output ...`

Comment: @pmf  With `yq` v4.x it is working fine but It is not working with `yq` v3.x. The functions like `select` and `load` are in the later version. Do have any alternatives for v3.x ?

Comment: @AvinashMishra mikefarah/yq v3.x is quite old (measured in intermediate releases, v3.4.1, the latest one in the v3.x series, came out 67 versions ago), and was unsurprisingly very different and limiting. In a nutshell, you needed to extract the list from the second file using `yq read file2.yaml app.list-data`, then prepend the target structure using `yq prefix file2.yaml default.app.service-v1.country.list`, to then merge it with the first file using `yq merge file1.yaml file2.yaml`. Alternatively, you could provide a yaml-encoded script file combining these steps: `yq write -s <script_file>`